# How to make a windows form show in VSTO

Tags: vb.net, winforms, vsto

For an excel VSTO add-in I am creating in VB.Net, I have a function which runs for a few minutes, so to prevent my users from getting impatient, I would like to show a progress bar.

So I've created a windows form with a progress bar and a label that can show the current activity. I try to make the window show with this code:

```
Dim progressBar As ProgressForm = New ProgressForm()
progressBar.BringToFront()
progressBar.Visible = True
progressBar.Show()
progressBar.Focus()
```

When I run this code, nothing happens. From the debugger, I can see the form in the memory, I can access its properties, but it does not show, not on top of the excel application, nor in task manager.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you running that code from  a button press or something? I've just had a quick try and opening a form on `_Statup` doesn't work. Putting the `Form.Show()` on a button does work.

Comment: @Malcor: Yes, when a certain button in the ADD-INS ribbon is pressed, this code is executed.

Comment: Is there anything in the constructor for your `ProgressForm` or on the Form load?

Comment: @Malcor: Not explicitly, but since the form is build using the designer (drag and drop controls onto it) I assumed it contains an automatically generated constructor? Or am I wrong?

Comment: exactly yes, that should be fine. Your're not accessing the progress bar control before the form has loaded?

Comment: @Malcor: No, even if I step through it with the debugger (so long wait times in between) I get the same result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124872/discussion-between-malcor-and-drdonut).

Answer (score 0):

I give an example of what is missing in your code :

```
with progressBar
.Minimum = 0 
.Maximum = 10
For i=0 to 10
.Value = i
Next i 
end with
```

For more info about this field, [read this article](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_progress_bar.htm)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that is taken care of within the progressBar control inside the form. The problem is that the entire form does not show...

Comment: maybe add a button in the form, you will put this code : `Msgbox("Visible : " & progressBar.Visible.ToString)` what's the result?

Comment: Then I get a message box saying "VisibleTrue", but I could already see that in the debugger as well... Could it be that windows forms does not work well with VSTO or something?